# Consider a string as a python code?

Tags: python

I really searched a lot for an answer to this question. And i'm still stuck.

Let me illustrate the problem with an example.

i have set up a class system for scatter_01_...,scatter_02..,scatter_03... Till scatter_99_..

```
class ScatterPref(AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__
    addon_prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences

    scatter_01_name                = StringProperty(name="Custom slot name",subtype='NONE',default="Custom01")
    scatter_01_type                = EnumProperty(name='Particle Type',description='particle rendering type',items =[('Collection','Collection','','COLLECTION_NEW',1),('Object','Object','','OBJECT_DATA',2),],default='Object')
    scatter_01_count               = IntProperty(name="Emission Number",subtype='NONE',default=1000,min=0)
    scatter_01_countispersquare    = BoolProperty(name="Emission Number is per square meters (be sure to apply the scale of the terrain)",subtype='NONE',default=True)
    scatter_01_countpersquare      = IntProperty(name="Emission Number per square meters",subtype='NONE',default=50,min=0)
    scatter_01_seed                = IntProperty(name="Emission Seed Value",subtype='NONE',default=5,min=0)
    #let say + 30 other parameters

    scatter_02_name                = StringProperty(name="Custom slot name",subtype='NONE',default="Custom01")
    scatter_02_type                = EnumProperty(name='Particle Type',description='particle rendering type',items =[('Collection','Collection','','COLLECTION_NEW',1),('Object','Object','','OBJECT_DATA',2),],default='Object')
    scatter_02_count               = IntProperty(name="Emission Number",subtype='NONE',default=1000,min=0)
    scatter_02_countispersquare    = BoolProperty(name="Emission Number is per square meters (be sure to apply the scale of the terrain)",subtype='NONE',default=True)
    scatter_02_countpersquare      = IntProperty(name="Emission Number per square meters",subtype='NONE',default=50,min=0)
    scatter_02_seed                = IntProperty(name="Emission Seed Value",subtype='NONE',default=5,min=0)
    #let say + 30 other parameters

    scatter_03_name                = StringProperty(name="Custom slot name",subtype='NONE',default="Custom01")
    scatter_03_type                = EnumProperty(name='Particle Type',description='particle rendering type',items =[('Collection','Collection','','COLLECTION_NEW',1),('Object','Object','','OBJECT_DATA',2),],default='Object')
    scatter_03_count               = IntProperty(name="Emission Number",subtype='NONE',default=1000,min=0)
    scatter_03_countispersquare    = BoolProperty(name="Emission Number is per square meters (be sure to apply the scale of the terrain)",subtype='NONE',default=True)
    scatter_03_countpersquare      = IntProperty(name="Emission Number per square meters",subtype='NONE',default=50,min=0)
    scatter_03_seed                = IntProperty(name="Emission Seed Value",subtype='NONE',default=5,min=0)
    #let say + 30 other parameters
```

The problem is that later i will need to use scatter_XX_... within the code.

```
if addon_prefs.scatter_01_use_band == True:
    print("hello world")
    #let say this is a super long script
```

and i'll need this code to work for every 99 scatter_XX_.. object. 
**to resolve this problem i would like to change the code easely and interactively witouth repeating myself exactly like we do with strings**

exactly like that

```
def hello_world_long_script(variable):
    if addon_prefs.string_to_code("scatter_"+variable+"_use_band") == True:
        print("hello world")
        #let say this is a super long script

hello_world_long_script(05)
#now my super long script is easely manipulable.
```

i'd be really happy to adapt my code like it was a string. any idea on how to do that please ?

Comment: Just trying to clarify/understand what your goal is, here: are you really adding addon preferences that require 99 * 30 parameter fields? I can't imagine anyone using such a layout, it seems like too many fields. I don't understand what a 'scatter' would be (but maybe it's not releveant to explaining what this is doing anyway...) Finally, is there some strong reason why you can't just use a list? (each entry in that list would contain the fields for one item, i.e. name,type,count,countispersquare, 30 other things..?

Comment: I'm sure I've suggested using the basic python method  `getattr` to you before.  ie `getattr(prefs, "somestringpropertyname", SomeDefaultValueIfItDoesn'tExist)`

Comment: @acro could you please show a little example example for this case ?